# Why does ManageR and rpy2 not work in QGIS (1.8.0-Lisboa)?

Tags: qgis, r

I have been trying to get R scripts to function and ManageR to work within QGIS (1.8.0-Lisboa). (Windows 7). Python2.7.5. Two problems indicated that R was not working in QGis.

First - when I run an R script there is not output in the pop-up window.
Second - when I click on ManageR (bottom right corner of Qgis) it tells me I should either install rpy2 or check my installation of rpy2.

So, installing (checking rpy2). This in itself has proved very problematic. I found the following posts and 'quick-fix' software:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928277/rpy2-and-python-installation-road-block
https://bitbucket.org/breisfeld/rpy2_w32_fix/issue/1/binary-installer-for-win32

followed the instructions but still to no avail. Sadly I am no computer genius. I can follow simple instructions but am not up to fixing anything myself. So, guys. This is as much a request as a question. (a) how to fix, (b) is anybody working to fix this?

many thanks
BW

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, ManageR is no longer maintained in QGIS, but there's a better way now:

In QGIS 2.0 there's a new Processing framework that allows you to run R scripts in a more simple and straightforward way. There are some example scripts that can examine.

If you are on Windows, all you need to do, after installing QGIS 2.0, is to go to the menu Processing -> Options and configurations-> Activate R provider->Select the main R folder in c:/Programs/R and double click on one of R scripts to make sure everything is fine.

For more information Processing/R:
http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html