# Is it possible to create and run custom R scripts in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, r, sextante

I am new to QGIS and most of the tutorials I have found are for 1.x and the overhaul has me confused.

I would like to create R scripts and run them in QGIS. I have read **[here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-raster-histogram-in-qgis-using-sextante-and-r/)** that it's possible using the SEXTANTE plugin.

It seems that SEXTANTE is part of the core install now and that it's been renamed to processing. I've found out how to make python scripts but not R.

Is it  possible to create and run custom R scripts in QGIS 2.0? If so, where do I go in the new processing function?

Comment: This was answered [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/74121/21312), even though the question is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is quite clear but I cannot see "R scripts" in my processing toolbox (even in advanced interface). I have QGIS 2.2 and only have "scripts". Is it the same or this means that R is not "linked" with QGIS ?

Comment: See Guillermo Olmedo's comment above (switch to _"Advanced interface"_). By the way, this is NOT a forum, you should have posted that one as comment on Guillermo's answer.

Comment: Arelien, did you enable r scripts? You can check if its enabled in the processing menu, in options and configuration

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can create and run R scripts in QGIS 2.0.

The basic sintaxis is the same as python, so start reading this:
http://www.qgis.org/es/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#creating-scripts-and-running-them-from-the-toolbox

Then you can check, some example scripts installed by default, in your processing panel.

If you need more help you can check some of my scripts:

https://github.com/INTA-Suelos/QGIS-R-Geostatistics

[image: QGIS interface showing processing toolbox]

Comment: If you don't see "R scripts" on your processing toolbox, you have to change from "Simplified interface" to "Advanced interface" using the dropdown menu at bottom