# How can I use a DBF layer in an R script in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, dbf

How can I use a DBF layer in an R script in QGIS?

For example, I can input a vector by using ##Layer=vector, and a CSV table with ##Table=table, but it will fail if the table is based on a DBF file.

I can export from DBF to CSV, but then I will loose the joins I have defined.

Comment: Not an **R** user but from a [FAQ](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/inputdata_R.htm) section, it mentions to download/install the _foreign_ package which would allow you to use the `read.dbf` function. There's also some more information [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.dbf.html) which includes an example on how to read dbf files. Hope this is of some help!

Comment: Thanks for the links. They are useful for importing a DBF in R and I may use the articles for a workaround but I'm more interested in QGIS providing the data directly to the R environment through a ## command for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS/Processing/R does not accept .dbf files. However there is a workaround that involves using the "foreign" package.

Create a script with a folder parameter and set its path to the folder where you stored your .dbf file. Then use this code to import the .dbf file into the R environment.

```
##Folder=folder
library(foreign)
x <- read.dbf("your_file.dbf")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Filipe, the foreign library workaround works great.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted this as an answer as it's too long for a comment. But atleast I can add an image!)*

I think you may need to install the `rpy` extension for Python as mentioned in this post: [Resources on using R in QGIS for R users?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76639/resources-on-using-r-in-qgis-for-r-users).

You should be able to install this extension using the [OSGeo4W setup](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) and selecting *Advanced Install* setting. Go through the options until you get to **Select Packages**. You can leave everything to *Default* if you don't care about other packages but in the search box, type `rpy` and you should get a *Libs* package with the rpy binding. Click the Skip message to change it:

[image: rpy extension]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Joseph for you additional comment. The Rpy library is another workaround worth to check.

Comment: @paul0207 - No worries buddy, glad you got it sorted!