# Exporting PNG from Command Line on Mac

Tags: qgis

I have set up a project in QGIS and can export maps using the Print Composer manually, but I want to have a single OSX Mac terminal command line that specifies the coordinates, the scale, and the dots per inch of a required map and it generates a PNG from my project?

Is this possible?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167650/export-a-qgis-print-composer-file-qpt-as-pdf-from-the-command-line?rq=1

Comment: Do you ask for an automated/scripted mapping in python using QGIS and MapComposer as a component in this script?