# Create interactive maps in R

Tags: r, fields-attributes

I am a `R` user and quite new in GIS.

From [Adding Attribute data to shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/adding-attribute-data-to-shapefile) I know how to add/edit attribute data (say population) to shapefile using `R`.

Now, I have some shapefiles with attribute data, and I know how to make a static map, but I would like to know if there is a way to make an interactive map in `R`, e.g. allow zooming, hover a region will display the corresponding attribute data in `R`.

If not, I have heard of a free and open-source GIS software [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), is it possible to do it using that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes with `leaflet`

- [Leaflet for R](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)
- [Using Leaflet with Shiny](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a few more pointers to the links mentioned in @nebi's answer:

- another Leaflet library: [`leafletR` on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leafletR/index.html)
- the [plotly ggplot2 library](https://plot.ly/ggplot2): see [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/12/interactive-2d-3d-plots-with-plotly-and-ggplot2.html) and [a series of example maps with code](https://plot.ly/r/#maps)
- [rCharts](http://rcharts.io/) provides bindings to the Leaflet library, [here is an example of a choropleth map](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?6735051#.VjJ_ia6rTdQ)
- [ggvis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggvis/index.html) can be [combined with with shiny](https://hrbrmstr.shinyapps.io/ggvis-maps/)

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this similar question posed at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040625/overlaying-shapefiles-or-raster-over-interactive-maps/34308916#34308916).

The **mapview** package has been developed for this particular purpose and allows you to interactively display any objects of class 'Spatial*' and 'Raster*'. Note that it also comes with a variety of background map layers for better spatial orientation. For a short introduction to what **mapview** is capable of, feel free to browse the [package vignette](http://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/web-presentations/20150723_mapView.html). Here, for example, is some code that displays the widely applied 'meuse' dataset from **sp** and, at the same time, allows you to interactively retrieve information from all the single data points. Check out `?mapview` to grow familiar with the numerous costumization options that the package offers.

```
## required packages
# install.packages("mapview")
library(mapview)
library(sp)

## import 'meuse' dataset
data("meuse")

coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

## create viewer (background layer 'OpenTopoMap')
mapview(meuse)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

QGIS is a GIS platform.  Designed for you to do analytical computations on a spatial document.  In short, you are making a map.  In R, you can also create analytical computations based on GIS statistical analysis.  The question is whether or not you are creating a spatial dashboard, or a mapping product.   Here is a couple of websites that will give you R-based GIS:

http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/index.html
http://spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
http://spatial.ly/r/  (If you are educated on ggplot2, this is good).

For R functionality in QGIS: 
[Resources on using R in QGIS for R users?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76639/resources-on-using-r-in-qgis-for-r-users)